# Getting Alt to Work in the Terminal with Tmux and Vim

Tags: terminal, vim, tmux

I'm trying to make `Alt + h/j/k/l` switch tmux panes and vim windows. Yet for some reason my terminal (xfce4-terminal) and and `Alt` do not play nicely with each other. I got `Alt + h/j/k/l` to switch windows in vim via the following script:

```
nnoremap <silent> <M-h> :TmuxNavigateLeft<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <M-j> :TmuxNavigateDown<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <M-k> :TmuxNavigateUp<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <M-l> :TmuxNavigateRight<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <M-\> :TmuxNavigatePrevious<cr>

let c='a'
while c <= 'z'
  exec "set <A-".c.">=\e".c
  exec "imap \e".c." <A-".c.">"
  let c = nr2char(1+char2nr(c))
endw
```

To be honest, I found the latter part of the above script off the internet, and don't understand what it's doing. **Now, in my tmux config I have:**

```
bind -n M-h if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-h" "select-pane -L"
bind -n M-j if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-j" "select-pane -D"
bind -n M-k if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-k" "select-pane -U"
bind -n M-l if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys M-l" "select-pane -R"
```

**The result is that I can switch windows in vim, but cannot switch panes in tmux.** How do I fix this? I"m running Arch Linux with xfce4 as my desktop environment. This problem seems to persist in xterm, xfce4-terminal, and gnome-terminal.